# How to identify what locked PL/SQL package (Oracle 10.0.4.2)?

Tags: oracle, session, plsql, locking

I was trying to recompile PL/SQL package and no avail. because something obtained the lock and that wasn't released for long time.  As soon as I kill all sessions I was able to recompile but encounter the same behavior (i.e. locked package) and I wonder what tools are avail to  identify what could of obtain it and never release it? This happen on  (Oracle 10.2.0.4).  Greatly appreciate for your help.

Comment: What session has locked a PL/SQL package? http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_session_locking_plsql_package.htm

Comment: That answer on dba-oracle.com isn't complete. The session may not be currently executing SQL that directly refers to the package (eg it may be through a synonym etc).

Comment: Further to @GaryMyers point, that script also doesn't handle upper/lower case correctly or one package that calls another.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you mean 10.2.0.4, as there isn't a 10.0.x.x version series.

```
select * from v$locked_object lo join dba_objects o on lo.object_id = o.object_id
where o.object_name = 'xxPACKAGE NAMExx' and o.object_type = 'PACKAGE';
```

Comment: Maybe use `select * from DBA_DDL_LOCKS where name like '%PACKAGE_NAME%' `

Answer (score 6):

```
select l.session_id, l.owner, l.name, l.type, inst_id, sql_id
     , a.sql_fulltext
     , 'alter system disconnect session '''||s.sid||','||s.serial#||',@'||inst_id||''' immediate' ddl
  from dba_ddl_locks l 
  join gv$session s on s.sid = l.session_id
  join gv$sqlarea a using(inst_id, sql_id)
 where l.name = 'OBJECT_NAME'  
;
```

Comment: That is for RAC. Remove g from gv$ for a single instance database.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, 
[including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) 
really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are 
answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might 
not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd 
your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both 
the code and the explanations!